# Notify second message after first message is hidden

Tags: angular, ngnotify

I want to show wait message and after wait message is disapper then only I want to show error message or success message. At the moment the code below I tried, wait message comes and inbetween error message appears.

How can I  fix this?

```
import { SnotifyService } from 'ng-snotify';
export class RequestResetComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private notify: SnotifyService,
        private user: UserService
    ) { }

    onSubmit = function () {
        this.notify.info('Wait...', {timeout: 2000});
        this.user.sendPasswordRestLink(this.form)
            .subscribe(
                res => this.handleResponse(res),
                err => this.notify.error(err.error.error)
            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use setTimeout for showing error or success message. I have applied timeout in error message please refer that.

```js
import { SnotifyService } from 'ng-snotify';
export class RequestResetComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private notify: SnotifyService,
        private user: UserService
    ) { }

    onSubmit = function () {
        this.notify.info('Wait...', {timeout: 2000});
        this.user.sendPasswordRestLink(this.form)
            .subscribe(
                res => this.handleResponse(res),
                err => { let clearTimeOut = window.setTimeout(()=>{window.clearTimeout(clearTimeOut); this.notify.error(err.error.error)},3000);}
            );
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: Thank you it worked. can you plz explain me this function

Comment: are you talking about 'setTimeout' function? setTimeout function is used where you want to execute your function after some time(provided time). In your code the problem was you are showing a notification and afterthat make a service call this all operation goes async. that' was the reason both are showing together. I have applied 3000 ms timeout in showing error message. till the time your notification will hide. for more information about settimeout https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: Note that the part of `clearTimeOut` is not necessary. The function provided as an argument to `setTimeout` only runs once.

Comment: Things get interesting once the callback of a `setTimeout` again calls the same function and that function also encloses some variables. But in this particular case, there's not going to be any memory leak.

Comment: Could you explain to me how this leaks memory?